# Script not running on start up, systemd ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, systemd, luigi

I am currently attempting to start Luigid when my Ubuntu server turns on, I have tried several techniques including rc.local, cronjob(@reboot), upstart, systemd and none of them appear to be working.

I should point out that the command runs fine if I do it manually, I just need it to run on startup. At this point I really don't have any concern which way I get it to work so here are some of the things I've tried -

**Cron:**

Used

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and entered

```
@reboot luigid --background --logdir /home/myuser/luigilog
```

**Systemd:**

I have a script in /usr/bin called luigid with the following contents, it is marked as executable, and I have tried it with and without "exit 0" fearing a proper exit code might be required -

```
#!/bin/sh
exec luigid --background --logdir /home/myuser/luigilog
```

and a service file in /etc/systemd/system/ called luigid.service -

```
[Unit]
Description=Luigid Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/luigid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried forking(and specifying the PIDfile in both the service and in the lugid command, oneshot and simple as the types with no luck.

I have enabled the service using -

```
systemctl enable luigid.service
```

It appears it attempts to start the service because checking the status using

`systemctl status luigid.service`

shows

```
luigid.service - Luigid Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/luigid.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2016-10-10 15:18:00 UTC; 18min ago

Oct 10 15:16:29 Analytics systemd[1]: Starting Luigid Service...
Oct 10 15:18:00 Analytics systemd[1]: luigid.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 10 15:18:00 Analytics systemd[1]: Failed to start Luigid Service.
Oct 10 15:18:00 Analytics systemd[1]: luigid.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 10 15:18:00 Analytics systemd[1]: luigid.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

There must be something obvious I'm missing, it really can't be this hard to get a command to run on startup!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing the startup options: Neither "rc.local" and "cron @reboot" will help you if the service crashes later, so they aren't ideal. Since it appears you have a systemd-based system, then Upstart isn't really an option. `systemd` is a good option to focus on because it will not only start your process, but also restart it if it crashes.

I don't know what the right option for `Type=` is for this service, but it does matter. Check the docs for `Type=` in `man systemd.service` to determine which one is correct for your service.

Your wrapper script shouldn't be required. You should be able to have an `ExecStart=` line like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/luigid --background --logdir /home/myuser/luigilog
```

I would also try removing the `--background` option and setting the `Type=` to `simple` if you haven't tried that combination.

If you can't get it to work, try get your daemon to provide more verbose logging about why it's not starting, or resort to adding `/usr/bin/strace` to the beginning of your `ExecStart=` line to get detailed logging of the system calls that the binary is making during startup. One of the final few calls could point to where it is hanging.

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks for the help.

Final solution was to use Type=Simple, remove the --background flag, and also specify the user for the service to run as.